# Google Apps - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am trying to get files from gdrive(google docs), but it returning the error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.The same error returning for Google Calendar also. I tried both DotNetOpenAuth and Oauth for authorize the user.

Error (from google calendar):

Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full?max-results=1&xoauth_requestor_id=mymail%40gmail.com&start-min=2013-12-04T12:37:34%2B05:30&sortorder=ascending&singleevents=true

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

My Code (google calendar):

```
        GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("writely", "AppName");
        requestFactory.ConsumerKey = "key";
        requestFactory.ConsumerSecret = "secret";

        String user = "mail@domain.com";

        DocumentsService client = new DocumentsService("AppName");
        client.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

        // Retrieve user's list of Google Docs
        DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
        query.Uri = new OAuthUri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full", user, requestFactory.ConsumerKey);

        DocumentsFeed feed = client.Query(query);

        foreach(DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
        }
```